# Position Sizing in Quantstrat based on symbol rank?

Tags: r, quantstrat

I am trying to create an algorithm that trades based on relative rankings. I.e, if Google is ranked #1, buy $100,000 at the start of the week and sell at the end. If Google is ranked #2, buy $50,000 at the start and sell at the end.

I've figured out how to get the system trading weekly, but I cannot figure out how to set up dynamic position sizing. I've attached the $ position values to my XTS files, so the system would need to look these up inline with the correct date/week.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks!

My current function is as follows. The "symbol[timestamp,26]" is trying to refer to the symbol XTS object at column 26 given a particular timestamp. However, I get an error that says "incorrect number of dimensions".

```
"osMaxDollar" <- function(data, timestamp, orderqty, ordertype, orderside,
                      portfolio, symbol, prefer="Open", tradeSize,
                      maxSize, integerQty=TRUE,
                      ...) {
  pos <- getPosQty(portfolio, symbol, timestamp)
  if(prefer=="Close") {
    price <- as.numeric(Cl(mktdata[timestamp,]))
  } else {
    price <- as.numeric(Op(mktdata[timestamp,]))
  }
  posVal <- pos*price
  if (orderside=="short") {
    dollarsToTransact = symbol[timestamp,26]
    #If our position is profitable, we don't want to cover needlessly.
    # if(dollarsToTransact > 0) {dollarsToTransact=0}
  } else {
    dollarsToTransact <- -symbol[timestamp,26]
    #If our position is profitable, we don't want to sell needlessly.
    # if(dollarsToTransact < 0) {dollarsToTransact=0}
  }
  qty <- dollarsToTransact/price
  if(integerQty) {
    qty <- trunc(qty)
  }
  return(qty)
}
```

Edit: This was my final solution for anyone that is curious

```
"osMaxDollar" <- function(data, timestamp, orderqty, ordertype, orderside,
                          portfolio, symbol, prefer="Open", tradeSize,
                          maxSize, integerQty=TRUE,
                          ...) {
  pos <- getPosQty(portfolio, symbol, timestamp)
  if(prefer=="Close") {
    price <- as.numeric(Cl(mktdata[timestamp,]))
  } else {
    price <- as.numeric(Op(mktdata[timestamp,]))
  }
  posVal <- pos*price
  #Negative mktdata due to buy bot sell top
  dollarsToTransact = mktdata[timestamp,26]
  qty <- dollarsToTransact/price
  if(integerQty) {
    qty <- trunc(qty)
  }
  return(qty)
```

Comment: For anyone wondering how to solve this...